# Error installing ruby on rails on windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems

I wanted to install ruby on rails for windows 10, following the same instructions of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-B_KUFNkQQ

When it finish the installation of ruby, I return to the console and after gem install rails, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Usuario>gem install rails --no-document
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mimemagic-0.3.9/ext/mimemagic
C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/ruby.exe -IC:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems -rrubygems C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake RUBYARCHDIR\=C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.7.0/mimemagic-0.3.9 RUBYLIBDIR\=C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.7.0/mimemagic-0.3.9
rake aborted!
Could not find MIME type database in the following locations: ["/usr/local/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml", "/opt/homebrew/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml", "/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml"]

Ensure you have either installed the shared-mime-info package for your distribution, or
obtain a version of freedesktop.org.xml and set FREEDESKTOP_MIME_TYPES_PATH to the location
of that file.

Tasks: TOP => default
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mimemagic-0.3.9 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.7.0/mimemagic-0.3.9/gem_make.out
```

I tried to solve making an update and "gem install mime-types-data" but stills with the same problem...

The Ruby Installer is Ruby+Devkit 2.7.2-1 (x64) and my ruby version is ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x64-mingw32]

Comment: Hi, and welcome!  I'm not a Windows user so I can't help with the details, but the error message says what to do next:

"Ensure you have either installed the shared-mime-info package for your distribution, or obtain a version of freedesktop.org.xml and set FREEDESKTOP_MIME_TYPES_PATH to the location
of that file."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69248078/mimemagic-install-error-could-not-find-mime-type-database-in-the-following-loc

Answer (score 13):

**Windows 10 ruby 2.6.2 install rails 6.0.0.rc1**

1. Download the shared-mime-info from https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/shared-mime-info/uploads/0440063a2e6823a4b1a6fb2f2af8350f/shared-mime-info-2.0.tar.xz
2. Extract the downloaded package with 7Zip or WinRAR.
3. Place it in a location of your choice e.g. "C:\package".
4. Set a new Environment Variable with a name: **FREEDESKTOP_MIME_TYPES_PATH** and
   browse value to the location e.g. C:\shared-mime-info 2.0\data\freedesktop.org.xml.in
5. Refresh terminal or CMD e.g. Command

> **refreshenv**

6. And finally, **gem install rails -v 6.0.0.rc1**

Comment: This was what I was looking for. Thanks heaps.

Comment: You just saved me alot of time! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

- windows 10
  ruby : 2.5.8

I downloaded package from https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/shared-mime-info/ and then set the environment variable (Windows) **FREEDESKTOP_MIME_TYPES_PATH** to that path ("c:....\data\freedesktop.org.xml.in")

also I installed mime-types-data >  ***gem install mime-types-data***

at first it didn't work after closing and opening again the terminal it did.

tip: if you use *vscode* you need to reopen vscode

- Mac

If you are using macOS, try the following

`brew install shared-mime-info`

`bundle update mimemagic`

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that the mimemagic team yanked a lot of versions yesterday https://rubygems.org/gems/mimemagic/versions
now you have to install the package shared-mime-info in your distribution.

I would recommend using WSL for rails development in windows, it will save a lot of problems in the future.

Answer (score 1):

## For MacOs or Linux - Install shared-mime-info package to resolve that issue.

### macOS

$ brew install shared-mime-info

### Debian, Ubuntu

apt-get update && apt-get install -y shared-mime-info

Answer (score 0):

after a quick google search, this seems appropriate:

from [MimeMagic Github Page](https://github.com/mimemagicrb/mimemagic#dependencies) :

> This process will also work on a Windows machine.
>
> 1. Download the package from
>    https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/shared-mime-info/download
> 2. Ensure the command line version of 7-Zip is installed
> 3. `7z x -so shared-mime-info_2.0-1_amd64.deb data.tar | 7z e -sidata.tar "./usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml"`
>
> Place the file
> freedesktop.org.xml in an appropriate location, and then set the
> environment variable FREEDESKTOP_MIME_TYPES_PATH to that path.
>
> Once that has been done the gem should install successfully.
>
> Please note
> that the gem will depend upon the file remaining in that location at
> run time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MacOS

```
Error:
Could not find MIME type database in the following locations: ["/usr/local/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml", "/opt/homebrew/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml", "/opt/local/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml",
"/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml"]
```

Then below 2 commands acts as a savior.

```
$ brew install shared-mime-info

$ gem install mimemagic -v '0.3.10' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed mimemagic-0.3.10
Parsing documentation for mimemagic-0.3.10
Installing ri documentation for mimemagic-0.3.10
Done installing documentation for mimemagic after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Then Run Bundle

```
$ bundle
$ bundle install
```